# Cookie не добавляются в POST-запрос

Tags: c#, post, cookie

Делаю авторизацию в CMS Xenforo. Сперва с помощью get-запроса получаю куки, а потом уже отправляю его в POST-запросе. Все бы ничего, да в сниффере я не вижу ни одной куки в post-запросе, хотя я добавил его в `CookieContainer.`

```
static CookieContainer Cookie = new CookieContainer();

public static void Get() {

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://xenforo.info/");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Cookie.Add(response.Cookies);
}

public static void Post() {

    Get();

    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://xenforo.info/login/login");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.CookieContainer = Cookie;

    var postData = "login=xxx";
    postData += "&register=0";
    postData += "&password=xxx";
    postData += "&cookie_check=1";
    postData += "&redirect=%2F";
    postData += "&_xfToken=";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Referer = " https://xenforo.info/";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36";
    using(var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать (и не надо хранить весь контейнер с куками, только сами куки):

```
    private static CookieCollection cook;

    public static void Get()
    {
        ...
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cook = response.Cookies;
    }

    public static void Post()
    {
        Get();

        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://xenforo.info/login/login");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://xenforo.info"), cook);
        ...
    }
```