# Не могу авторизоваться на сайте и парсить

Tags: c#, auth, httpwebrequest

Не могу авторизоваться на сайте ,а потом парсисть

```
public string send(string url, string par)
    {
        String secondStepForm3 = par;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "Opera/9.80";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = container;
        byte[] EncodedPostParams3 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(secondStepForm3);
        request.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams3.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams3, 0, EncodedPostParams3.Length);
        request.GetRequestStream().Close();

        HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://edu.tatar.ru/user/diary/term");
        req2.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse();
        string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
        return html;
    }
```

send("http://edu.tatar.ru/logon", "main_login=*****&main_password=*****")

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужна Response-кука которая после POST, а не Request-кука, потому что регистрационные куки даются после логина а не до.

Comment: Можно подробнее?Если не сложно с кодом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755433/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-post-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704791/cookie-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81 вот это скорее всего уже ваше

Comment: request - вы даже не запросили response - поэтому кукисы пусты.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cookie не добавляются в POST-запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704791/cookie-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/G7NrkJHf @nick_n_a посмотрите , что не так

Comment: Не могу сказать, не вижу передались вам куки или нет. Посмотрите вопрос с ответом по ссылке.

Comment: Ничего не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Во первых: данный ресурс ограничивает доступ к методу пост по IP !**

переведите сообщение `Restricted IP`.